# Using hook_theme_registry_alter()

Tags: hooks

I am using `hook_theme_registry_alter()` in my custom module for overriding the theme function. 
I have done something like this in my module file aml.module

```
function aml_theme_registry_alter (&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['aml']['function'] = 'theme_menu_item_link';
  dsm($theme_registry);

}

function theme_menu_item_link () {
  drupal_set_message("hello");
}
```

I don't know how and where to implement this function **theme_menu_item_link**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to alter a `$theme_registry['aml']['function']` which doesn't exist.

Try have a look through the `$theme_registry` array, and find what you want to override, put this in where you currently have "['aml']". I am guessing you want "['menu_item_link']", but you will have to check.

Then change `theme_menu_item_link` to `aml_menu_item_link`.

Comment: Hey I have done as you have mentioned. Overridden ['menu_link']['function'] = 'theme_menu_link' and changed the function name from theme_menu_link to aml_menu_link() and dispalyed some simple text but still not getting any output

Comment: Have you cleared cache? You must clear cache each time with this function. Also is menu_link in the $them_registry array? Also to confirm this code will need to be in a custom module named aml not in the template.php

Comment: yes I have created a custom module named aml and have put this code in .module file. Tell me if there is any other option to override theme function in a module file instead altering theme registry as I want to provide page specific visibility to menu items through my module

Comment: I dont think there is a another hook which would do the same thing as it would need to have the full $theme_registry array with additional properties added by _theme_process_registry().

have you tried looking at altering the menu's themselves? You could try hook_menu_link_alter with some if statements to unset menu items?

Comment: yes I have used hook_form_form_id_alter in my module for menu edit item form. With the help of this hook I implemented the user interface for my module. Just like in block module there are visibility settings option by which the user can choose the path on which  the menu link has to be active.